# Expectation of Brownian Motion increments

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I'm following Oksendal's book and during the construction of the Ito integral he uses the expectation of two different **simple functions** to demonstrate that where you choose the interior point of each interval of the partition is important for defining the correct integral. However, during that argument he chooses $\phi_2=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1} B_{t_{j+1}}\cdot\chi_{[t_j,t_{j+1})}$. Then he makes the following argument for some partition $\Pi_n=\{0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T\}$

$$\mathbb{E}(\int_0^T\phi_2\>dB_t)=\mathbb{E}[\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})]=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})].$$

This, I am fully ok with and understand, however it is this next line that I don't understand:

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[B_{t_{j+1}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})]=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}[(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_j})^2].$$

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $t>s$, then

$$E[B_t(B_t-B_s)]=E[(B_s + (B_t-B_s))(B_t - B_s)] \\
= E[B_s(B_t-B_s)] + E[(B_t-B_s)^2] \\
= E[B_s] E[B_t-B_s] + E[(B_t-B_s)^2] \\
 = E[(B_t-B_s)^2].$$

The third equality basically follows by the Markov property. More precisely you can condition on $B_s$, use the Markov property for each fixed $B_s$, and then integrate over the possible choices of $B_s$; this procedure is called "applying the tower property of conditional expectation" or just "applying the tower property". The other equalities are straightforwardly justified.

Comment: Thanks for that! Sorry to be a bit slow, but could you expand a bit on the Markov property step? I'm not really familiar with the conditioning step etc.

Comment: @J.Smith In conditional expectation notation you have $E[B_s(B_t-B_s)]=E[E[B_s(B_t-B_s) \mid B_s]]=E[B_s E[B_t-B_s \mid B_s]]=E[B_s \cdot 0]=0$. What I was describing is a little bit more elementary but the notation is a bit more annoying, it is essentially (for continuous $X,Y$) $E[XY]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty E[XY \mid X=x] f_X(x) dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xE[Y \mid X=x] f_X(x) dx$, then $E[Y \mid X=x]=E[Y]$ when $Y$ is independent of $X$.